# Slimscroll scrollbar not moving when content scrolled by scrollBy or scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I have a slimscroll applied content. I scroll to a content by using `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` parameters. Ex:

```
$element.slimScroll({scrollBy : '100px'});
```

It works and content is scrolled by given amount. However, scrollbar does not move and stays at top position and when I try to scroll the content by mouse wheel it will start to scroll from the top position, not from where I scrolled to by javascript. So, at first mouse wheel scroll, I see the content at the top, not the content below where I scrolled with javascript.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert to slimscroll version 1.3.1. A change in later versions cause this problem.

Btw, slimscroll mouse wheel scroll not workink properly on mozilla firefox. It either goes to the top or bottom, you cannot scroll it properly. To solve that problem:

Find the following line in the slimscroll file and remove or comment out:

```
this.addEventListener('MozMousePixelScroll', _onWheel, false );
```

If you are editing the minified version delete the following:

```
,this.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll",r,!1)
```

Comment: There is no match of `MozMousePixelScroll` `Version: 1.3.6`